# Aligning around different places in one environment

Tags: align, amsmath

My code is:

```
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{x \to a} [f(x)g(x)-LM] &= \lim\limits_{x \to a}[h(x)M+i(x)L+h(x)i(x)]
\\
&= \lim\limits_{x \to a} h(x)M+ \lim\limits_{x \to a}i(x)L+ \lim\limits_{x \to a} h(x)i(x) \\
&= 0\\
\therefore \lim\limits_{x \to a} [f(x)g(x)-LM] &= \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)g(x) - LM = 0 \\
\therefore \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)g(x) &= LM
\end{align*}
```

which outputs:
[image]

I want:

[image]

I've tried:

```
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{x \to a} [f(x)g(x)-LM] &= \lim\limits_{x \to a}[h(x)M+i(x)L+h(x)i(x)]
\\
&= \lim\limits_{x \to a} h(x)M+ \lim\limits_{x \to a}i(x)L+ \lim\limits_{x \to a} h(x)i(x) \\
&= 0
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
&\therefore \lim\limits_{x \to a} [f(x)g(x)-LM] = \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)g(x) - LM = 0 \\
&\therefore \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)g(x)= LM
\end{align*}
```

which gives:
[image]

I would prefer a non-manual and non-tedious way - thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `alignat*{2}` if you have two alignment points (which requires 3 `&`).

Unrelated: you don't have to add `\limits` in display style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
 & \lim_{x \to a} [f(x)g(x)-LM] & & = \lim\limits_{x \to a}[h(x)M+i(x)L+h(x)i(x)]
\\
 & & &= \lim_{x \to a} h(x)M+ \lim\limits_{x \to a}i(x)L+ \lim\limits_{x \to a} h(x)i(x) \\
 & & &= 0\\
\therefore{} & \lim_{x \to a} [f(x)g(x)-LM] & &= \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)g(x) - LM = 0 \\
\therefore {}& \lim_{x \to a} f(x)g(x)= LM
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]